# Calling gradle resValue from another file results in "Error:Gradle DSL method not found: 'resValue()'"

Tags: android, function, gradle, groovy, resources

I have the following problem.

I have one main file app.gradle where I call

```
defaultConfig {
    resValue "string", "hello world", "1234567890"
}
```

This works ok.
Now I'm trying to move that functionality to another file imported on the header with

```
apply from: "gradle_tasks.gradle"
```

With the following content:

```
ext.AddResourcesVariables = { ->
    resValue "string", "hello world", "1234567890"
}
```

And call it from the main gradle with

```
defaultConfig {
   AddResourcesVariables()
}
```

Then I've got the following error:

```
Error:Gradle DSL method not found: 'resValue()'
```

Am I missing some import?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`resValue()` is a dsl method from `defaultConfig`. You can't import it.

You could define a map of [type][name][value] in a different file

```
ext.valueMap = [
   [type: "string", name: "hello world", value: "1234567890"],
   [type: "string", name: "hello world", value: "1234567890"],
]
```

And then in the script, you iterate over it

```
defaultConfig{
  valueMap.each {
    resValue it.type, it.name, it.value
  }
}
```

Haven't compile it, but should be close.

Comment: Yes that's how I'm doing it now, but I was wandering why I cannot call resValue from that script. Maybe I can send defaultConfig class on that function

Comment: Your answer works in your exact case, but what if I want to create a function that generates this map, then the error shows up again `Error:Gradle DSL method not found: 'resValue()' `

Comment: I've finally send the defaultConfig variable through the function parmeter, and now I can call, defaultConfig.resValue(...)

Comment: how did you send it?